# Division using select statement in mysql

Tags: sql, group-by, division

I'm trying to divide two select queries but I have a problem in the divisor which throws "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"

This is what my statement looks like

The below statement works fine giving me a list of summed values grouped by col2:

```
(select sum(Tab1.col1) from Tab1 where
 Tab1.col2 in(select Tab1.col2 from Tab1 join Tab2 on Tab2.col2=Tab1.col2 ) 
 and Tab1.col3='general_consumption' group by Tab11.col2);
```

However when I use it the above query like below:

```
(Select (Tab1.Col4)from Tab1) /(select sum(Tab1.col1) from Tab1 where
 Tab1.col2 in(select Tab1.col2 from Tab1 join Tab2 on Tab2.col2=Tab1.col2 ) 
 and Tab1.col3='general_consumption' group by Tab11.col2);
```

I get this error:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Let me know if I can use it any other way.

Comment: This is giving you more than 1 row of records -  Select (Tab1.Col4)from Tab1. The Numerator should also output 1 row of records. It can also be an aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem

> Select (Tab1.Col4)from Tab1

It is returning all the rows

The correct syntax is this:

> Select (Tab1.Col4)/ (select sum(Tab1.col1) from Tab1 where Tab1.col2
>   in(select Tab1.col2 from Tab1 join Tab2 on Tab2.col2=Tab1.col2 ) and
>   Tab1.col3='general_consumption' group by Tab1.col2) from Tab1;